# Properly Exporting My Eclipse Project as a Runnable Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Hello I am working on a project in Eclipse and am trying to export it so I can send it to some friends. I am clueless as to how to export so I watched some YouTube videos because that's all I could find on the topic. The video said to;

1. File > Export
2. Java > Runnable Jar
3. Next
4. Set the project launch config, export location, and library config. (I am using lwjgl and slick 2d) so I selected "Package required libraries into generated JAR".

Then I attempted to launch it on my desktop from double-click, nothing. Then I tried from command prompt with "java -jar my_jar_name.jar" and it threw this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
        at javaGame.Game.main(Game.java:37)
        ... 5 more
```

Here is my main method in my project:

FYI: The first line is line #34 and the last is #43

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AppGameContainer appgc;
    try{
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(appgc.getScreenWidth(), appgc.getScreenHeight(), true);
        appgc.start();
    }catch(SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If more info is needed please let me know! 
P.S. This is the first Java project in Eclipse I have wanted to export so no I have not done it before.

Comment: Does the app run in eclipse OK?  You must be missing a jar somewhere

Comment: Yes it runs flawless in eclipse, if I am missing a jar it's not something I noticed.

Comment: Use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after referencing another Stack Overflow question I just found moments ago. I used JarSplicer to create a Fat Jar that included the natives into my jar and it worked perfectly. I can now run my app by double clicking it and it runs just like in Eclipse, thank you for your support!

[Exporting eclipse project to jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132671/exporting-eclipse-project-to-jar)

Answer (score 1):

***You may run your jar like this:***

```
java -jar my_jar_name.jar main_class_name
```

main_class_name is the class name that contains your main method

***You may also check if you have successfully created a jar with all the dependencies, here's how I add library jars:***

Select the project, and perform the following steps:

```
Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Select Libraries tab -> Add External JARS
```

Alternatively, you may create a folder called `lib`, and put the jar in the `lib` directory, then you may perform the following steps:

```
Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Select Libraries tab -> Add JARS
```

Comment: I already had all of that. I was actually following a tutorial on it from thenewboston.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to native libraries, when you are running the app the required library is not found. I am assuming you a have followed the instructions at

http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Eclipse

to run your app you have to

```
java -Djava.library.path="<path to lwjgl native files>" -jar my_jar_name.jar
```

Comment: Same error, my project (Game) is called Homefront Defense so I used this in command prompt because it is the same in the lwjgl build path properties: java -Djava.library.path="Homefront Defense/lib/natives/windows" -jar HomefrontDefense_Alpha0.1.jar